# How an Aurelia binding behavior could enhance an innerHTML content?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, aurelia

In my web app I'm using a Markdown value converter to render HTML from a Markdown string, e.g.

```
<div innerhtml.bind="string | markdown"></div>
```

This works nice and inside the `div` I get an HTML rendering of the Markdown content in `string`.

The value converter is able to render an Aurelia custom element in the output, but being that element inside the value converter output as a string, it's not enhanced by the Aurelia's templating engine.

Would a binding behavior be able to use the `TemplatingEngine` to enhance the output of the value converter once rendered in the DOM, every time the source value changes? Something like:

```
<div innerhtml.bind="string | markdown & enhance"></div>
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work (it's being evaluated before `target` gets its children):

```
export class EnhanceBindingBehavior {

    private templatingEngine: TemplatingEngine;

    public constructor(templatingEngine: TemplatingEngine) {
        this.templatingEngine = templatingEngine;
    }

    public bind(binding: Binding, scope: Scope): void {
        let target: HTMLElement = binding["target"];
        for (let i = 0; i < target.children.length; i++) {
            console.log("enhancing element " + i);
            this.enhance(target.children[i]);
        }

    }

    public unbind(binding: Binding, scope: Scope): void {

    }

    private enhance(element: Element): void {
        this.templatingEngine.enhance({
            element: element
        });
    }
}
```

Would it be possibile at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding behavior's `bind` method is invoked [immediately before](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/blob/1.0.0-beta.1.3.6/src/binding-expression.js#L86-L88) the binding instance [applies the model value to the target element](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/blob/1.0.0-beta.1.3.6/src/binding-expression.js#L99-L100) which explains why the div's children don't exist yet- the `string | markdown` part of the binding expression hasn't been applied yet.

I think an aurelia custom attribute would be a better fit for this use-case.  Something like:

```html
<div enhance.bind="myMarkdownString | markdown">
```

Or even:

```html
<div enhanced-markdown.bind="myMarkdownString">
```

Either of these would give you better control over the process.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Jeremy answer, I made this custom attribute:

```
export class EnhancedCustomAttribute {

    private templatingEngine: TemplatingEngine;

    private element: HTMLElement;

    private value: string;

    public constructor(templatingEngine: TemplatingEngine, element: Element) {
        this.templatingEngine = templatingEngine;
        this.element = <HTMLElement> element;
    }

    public valueChanged(html: string) {
        this.enhance(html);
    }

    private enhance(html: string) {
        this.element.innerHTML = html;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.element.children.length; i++) {
            this.templatingEngine.enhance(this.element.children.item(i));
        }
    }

}
```